# How to add multiple 'OR' and 'AND' condition in a if block in Scala template in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

**messageViewer.scala.html**

```
@(formData: Map[String, String] )
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="sv">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Java Play - Scala Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @if(formData.get("nockOutRuleStatus1").equals("SUBMITTED") && formData.get("nockOutRuleStatus2").equals("APPROVED")){
            //This statement should execute. But it is not executed.
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg hide-element" id="openSuccessModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#successModal">Success</button>
        }
        @if(formData.get("nockOutRuleStatus1").equals("REJECTED") || formData.get("nockOutRuleStatus2").equals("AUTO-REJECTED")){
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg hide-element" id="openErrorModalBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#errorModal">Error</button>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

From my java controller(**messageCtrl.java**) I am passing the Map type formData.

```
Map<String, String> formData = new HashMap<String, String>();
formData.put("nockOutRuleStatus1","SUBMITTED");
formData.put("nockOutRuleStatus2","APPROVED");
return ok(messageViewer.render(formData));
```

But the statement inside the first `IF` block, is not executed.

Comment: What is `PrgmType`? Is it an enum of some sort? You probably want to check `prgmType.toString == "Java"`?

Comment: @cbley ```PrgmType``` is a ```String``` and I have to check both conditions inside the if block. Is it possible to put two or more conditions using an operator like '&&', '||' in sala template of play framework?

Comment: Twirl (as it should be mentioned is what's used there) complies with Scala syntax, so it's recommended to first have a look at the [basic documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html). Also using/accepting `null` is not recommended (as using `equals` not required for immutable type like `String`)

Comment: So, you have `type PgrmType = String` in your code somewhere? As cchantep mentioned, you don't need to check for null in Scala, since the `==` operator does that for you. So, you only need to use `@if(prgmType == "Java")`.

Comment: @cbley That I understand. But instead of Null check, suppose there is a condition saying ```@if(prgmType == "Java" && prgmType == "Scala") {do something}else{do something else.}```. Can I put two condition using ```&&``` operator or ```||``` operator in Play Scala template.

Comment: Yes, you can. The Twirl template is compiled down to Scala code, with the same semantics. If the code in the if-block is not run, you probably have some error in your condition.

Comment: That being said, you need to show us more context. Prepare a minimal compilable example...

Comment: @cbley I have updated the question description. Have a look.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but when I run your example, I see the `//This statement should execute. But it is not executed.` comment and also the button. Try to pinpoint the problem by rendering the map inside the template, a la `@formData.mkString(", ")` -- is this what you had expected?